# Смущает пример из "Java concurrence in practice"

Tags: java, concurrency

Меня терзают смутные сомнения относительно thread-safety этого класса:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class MonitorVehicleTracker {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Map<String, MutablePoint> locations;

    public MonitorVehicleTracker(Map<String, MutablePoint> locations) {
        this.locations = deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized Map<String, MutablePoint> getLocations() {
        return deepCopy(locations);
    }

    public synchronized  MutablePoint getLocation(String id) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        return loc == null ? null : new MutablePoint(loc);
    }

    public synchronized  void setLocation(String id, int x, int y) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        if (loc == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such ID: " + id);
        loc.x = x;
        loc.y = y;
    }

    private static Map<String, MutablePoint> deepCopy(Map<String, MutablePoint> m) {
         Map<String, MutablePoint> result = new HashMap<String, MutablePoint>();
         for (String id : m.keySet())
            result.put(id, new MutablePoint(m.get(id)));
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
}
```

Собственно, два вопроса:

1) почему deepCopy выполнен как static? Тут ведь разный monitor lock для инстанса класса и для собственно объекта Class

2) по-моему коллекции *locations* ничего не мешает измениться в процессе deepCopy, или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. static, потому что не обращается к состоянию класса. Сам метод приватный, что исключает его вызов из вне.
2. Коллекция locations нигде не модифицируется.

Единственная неприятность, которая здесь может случиться, это модификация коллекции, которая передана в конструктор, в процессе выполнения deepCopy. Но это уже зависит от клиента класса.

Comment: получается, что deepCopy вызывается потоком, который взял монитор инстанса?

Comment: @Vladimir Kishlaly нет, т.к. он не синхронизирован. Но это и не важно. Сам deepCopy не изменяет состояния `locations` и никакой другой метод этого не делает. Поэтому метод `deepCopy` может быть безопасно вызван без блокировки.